# I want to use a base class but I dont want calling apps to know about it how do I do this? c#

Tags: c#

I have class library with c#. With the class 'student'. And it inherits from 'person'.

I want users of the class library to be able to instantiate the class student but not person.

I tried the following:

```
public class person
```

and

```
private class student : person
```

But I get the compile error:

> Elements defined in a namespace cannot
>   be explicitly declared as private,
>   protected or protected internal.

Why is this? I want to expose person but not the underlying base types.

Answer (score 10):

Declare your Person class as `abstract`. This means it cannot be instantiated.

An abstract class cannot be instantiated as an object and is only provided for the purpose of deriving subclasses.

```
public abstract class Person
{
 // members here
}

public class Student : Person
{
 // members here
}
```

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx)  for more information.

Comment: how about in cases where you need to instantiate a person class? Would you recommend perhaps a BasePerson class that is abstract and then an inherited class called Person? Then have all other classes inherit BasePerson?

Comment: @Joel probably do it that way, yea :)

Answer (score 2):

I would make the `Person` class `abstract`.

EDIT: What AndyC said!

Answer (score 1):

make person abstract and public, this will prevent anyone instantiating it. Then student should be public.

There are some other alternatives, make student's constructor private and add a static method to Create on the class for example.

Edit: What anothershrubery said :)

Comment: I think you mean person constructor private, but this is was I was going to suggest and is how the .NET framework does it.  Making the entire class abstract causes more issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your base class cannot be `public` if you want to define an inherting class as `private`.  I think the answer you want in to make `Person` an `abstract` class.

Answer (score 0):

Making Person abstract is one way, generally the best way. However it's not always feasible; there may be a case in your own code in which you simply need a Person, but still don't want instances of the base class to be instantiated outside your control.

If you need to do this, make Person public and not abstract, but make its constructor(s) internal. This will allow the constructor to be called only from code in the same assembly, so you can instantiate a base Person do to behind-the-scenes work while still preventing instantiation of the base class by external code.

You can also make all the classes (Person and Student) private or internal, but then define a public factory class that will hand out instances derived from Person as implementations of a public interface IPerson. This allows you to control not only access to the actual classes, but instantiation and hydration of those classes. This would be good if Student or Person required other resources that external code shouldn't know about directly, or if you implement security that restricts access to data in Person or Student.